# Facebook iFrame tab problem with secure url (https)

Tags: facebook, iframe, ssl, https, facebook-iframe

i am making a facebook tab which using iframe to show the tab content from other url. Everything work fine but when users use secure http connection (https) the tab no longer loads and shows error saying page not secure.

The pages that the iframe showing is not using ssl. Do i need to have a ssl to show the page in secure connection or i have to change some setting in facebook?

Comment: What browser version? This is very likely a dupe of other questions here on SO.

Comment: @EricLaw -MSFT: i think all browsers. The thing is in the application settings it says to put secure url for the tabs and canvas page. If i dont put the secure url when users browsing with https have 404 error and when i put it the browser says the connection is not secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to buy an SSL certificate, make sure it is properly installed on your server, and make sure your the page is properly working over SSL (no warnings).  Once this is setup, plug the SSL url of your page onto your fan page tab application settings, and it will work.  You will want to do this as Facebook is continually encouraging users to enable the always-on SSL option on their account, and at some point SSL may be the only option on Facebook and they probably won't give you much of a warning to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

for now it's an option to have ssl certificate but starting from October the first, it will be required
i have set up my application, it works well for almost all browsers except google chrome, it seems to have a warning about my secure url of the ifram and doesnt load it, the only way i could work around it is visiting the actual url of the iframe, confirmed the ssl warning, then went back to the application on fb, so it finally worked
lousy solution i know, but there was nothing else i could do